# VBA Loop combining Lastrow and finding blank values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to build a "data check" type file where a series of macros look at a data set and copy/paste incorrect entries into separate sheets based on various criteria. One of these is looking at if the value in Column A is blank.

Below is the code that I currently have. It only takes the first instance of the blank, and I am trying have it loop to find all the blank values in column A.

```
Sub copy_blanks()  
    Dim sr As Range
    Dim blank As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet

    Set s1 = Worksheets("data")
    Set s2 = Worksheets("No LoadID")

    lr2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Set sr = Worksheets("data").Range("A:A").Find("")

    If Not sr Is Nothing Then  
        blank = sr.Row
        s1.Rows(blank).Copy
        s2.Cells(lr2 + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the whole row to be copied when you have a blank?

Comment: @urdearboy Yes I would like to bring over the whole row, is this still satisfied with the below?

Comment: Yup. Looks like all 3 solutions are grabbing the entire row

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help! All the answers proved to be useful and I will be able to integrate methods from each into the remainder of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Range.SpecialCells Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.SpecialCells).
You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to find all blank cells in a range.

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = Worksheets("data")

Dim LastDataRow As Range
Set LastDataRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) 'last used cell in column A

Dim wsNoID As Worksheet
Set wsNoID = Worksheets("No LoadID")

Dim BlankCells As Range
On Error Resume Next 'next line will throw an error if no blanks are found
Set BlankCells = wsData.Range("A1", LastDataRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) 'find all blank cells in column A until last data row
On Error Goto 0 're-activate error messages!

If Not BlankCells Is Nothing Then
    BlankCells.EntireRow.Copy

    wsNoID.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
    MsgBox "No blanks found."
End If
```

Comment: Was going to answer with the `SpecialCells` method - would need to add an error handler in case there's no blank cells.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Correct. Thank you for pointing out. Fixed it.

Comment: Sorry to stick my oar in again - `Set BlankCells = wsData.Range("A1", LastDataRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` would throw the error.  Could be a rare case of `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook My bad again :( I'm getting a coffee now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using autofilter for this sort of work since that will capture cells that are blank as the result of formulas (and thus contain `""` so they look blank) as blank as well as actually blank cells.  Code assumes headers are row 1 and actual data starts in row 2:

```
Sub copy_blanks()

    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Dim lr2 As Long

    Set s1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    Set s2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("No LoadID")

    lr2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With s1.Range("A1:A" & s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter 1, "="
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy
        s2.Cells(lr2 + 1, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You question implies you will have more criteria to search for so I decided to keep the loop. You can add more criteria here as you go ~

1. Loop through `Column A`
2. If value is blank add the cell to a `Union` (collection of cells)
3. Once loop is complete, copy the `Union` all at once

---

This can be improved upon by switching from a `For i` loop to a `For Each` loop to go through a range. Another way to do this is simply filter `Column A` by blanks and copy/paste the visible rows that remain.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Blanks()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
Dim db As Worksheet: Set db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("No LoadID")

Dim LROw As Long, i As Long, Blanks As Range

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = "" Then
        If Not Blanks Is Nothing Then
            Set Blanks = Union(Blanks, ws.Range("A" & i))
        Else
            Set Blanks = ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not Blanks Is Nothing Then
    Blanks.EntireRow.Copy db.Range("B" & db.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1).Row
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `db.Range("A" & db.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` must be `db.Range("B" & db.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1)` because there is no data in column A if you copy the rows (only having a blank in A).